# Extracting Value of Label from Select Statement in Django View

Tags: python, django, templates, drop-down-menu, view

I have the following code in a Django view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    image_filter_key_index = form.cleaned_data['image_filter_key']
    image_filter_key_label = dict(form.fields['image_filter_key'].choices)[image_filter_key_index]
```

I am trying to extract the label associated with the key chosen by a user via a select on a Django template. The dictionary for the select is as follows: {1: 'Male', 2: 'Female'}.

The error thrown is as follows: KeyError: u'1'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the keys are integers, but `image_filter_key_index` is a unicode char `u'1'`. You need to convert it first then try to access the label:

```
image_filter_key_label = dict(form.fields['image_filter_key'].choices)[int(image_filter_key_index)]
```